# Navigation between multiple windows in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

navigate windows each other within same space. when button pressed in one window replaced by next window at this place or navigate windows like in ipod navigation based app.

Answer (score 0):

It is window or view? This answer is for navigating in views

For navigating between the different views you have to use UINavigation controller http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Hints: ‘desktop’, ‘window’, ‘cocoa’. ;-)

Comment: i used navigation controller in my code but it says error: request for member 'navigationController' in something not a structure or union
i think it is used for iphone app not for desktop app

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you navigate from current XIB to another.

viewObject *objExm=[[viewObject alloc]init];
[self.view addSubView:objExam.view]

Comment: i tried this one [self.view addSubView:objExam.view] but showing error: request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NSWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation, especially `frame`, `setFrame:`, and `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`